# How to show one Item at a time from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I wonder if anyone can help, I'd like to Iterate over ArrayList but One item at a time with help of some button so when I press that button it would show me the next item in the list and so forth. Or if there's another way I'd be happy to take any advice. I'm trying to design a test so a student would get one question at a time he/she would submit the answer and it would move to the next question. This is what I have as showing full list on JSP.
My Servlet

```
        String vassId = request.getParameter("vassId");
        List<Assessment> qList = new ArrayList<Assessment>();
        Assessment qObj = null;
        DbConnection dbConn = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement proc = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            dbConn = new DbConnection();
            conn = DbConnection.connection();

            String dbCall = "{ ? = call pa_customer_admin.fn_list_question(?) }";
            proc = DbConnection.connection().prepareCall(dbCall);
            proc.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            proc.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(vassId));
            proc.execute();
            rs = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
            while (rs.next()) {
                qObj = new Assessment();
                qObj.setVassId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)));
                qObj.setDescr(rs.getString(2));
                qObj.setQuesStatus(rs.getString(3));
                qObj.setQuesTypeCode(rs.getString(4));
                qObj.setCreatedDate(rs.getString(6));
                qObj.setQuestion(rs.getString(7));
                qObj.setMark(rs.getString(8));
                qObj.setTimeLimit(rs.getInt(9));
                qList.add(qObj);
            }
            request.setAttribute("qObj", qObj);
            request.setAttribute("qList", qList);
            proc.close();
```

JSP

```
                   <form action="AnswerSaveProcess" method="POST" >
                    <c:if test="${empty qList}">
                        Empty list
                    </c:if> 
                    <c:if test="${! empty qList}">
                        <c:forEach items="${qList}" var="q">
                            <label>Question</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%= vassId%>">
                            <textArea readonly="readonly">${q.question}</textarea>
                            <input type="text" value="${q.mark}" readonly="readonly">                              
                            <input type="hidden" id="userTime" value="${q.timeLimit}" />

                            <label>Answer 1</label>
                            <input type="text"  ><input name="ansStatusCode" type="radio"><br/>
                            <label>Answer 2</label>
                            <input type="text" ><input name="ansStatusCode" type="radio"><br/>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Answer">
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:if>
                </form>
```

Comment: It sounds to me like this is not really a question on the ArrayList data structure as such, but a question on the management of state in a JSP page or web session (the text of the question does not mention JSP, but it is tagged as such)

Comment: Yes Simon I'm working with Servlet and creating an ArrayList from database and displaying it on JSP.

Comment: Store current index, and show content on index from array list, when next just do index++;

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList implements the Iterable interface and has index-based access to its members. All you need is to read some Java docs on usage examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to display one item at a time any thoughts on that ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator--

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--

Like I said, it's all in the Java docs.

Comment: @DmytroZnaiko You may wanna add those as comments than answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (untested):

```
final List<String> questions = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"question1", "question2", "question3"});
JButton b = new JButton("Press Me");
final JLabel label = new JLabel();
final cnt = 0;
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    pubic void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText(question.get(cnt++));
        if(cnt > questions.size()) cnt = 0; 
    }
});
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getConentPane().add(b);
frame.getConentPane().add(label);
frame.setSize(800,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but question is tagged `jsp`.

Comment: Oh, my fault...I nevertheless leave the answer, as the logic stays the same

Answer (score 0):

As it's an ArrayList you can use indexing.  When the button is pressed increment the index and get the next item from the ArrayList.

Example

```
package items;

import java.util.List;

public class GetNextItem {

    private static int itemIndex;

    private List<String> itemList;

    // Constructor with itemList
    public GetNextItem(List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        itemIndex = 0; // start at the first item.
    }

    /**
     * Get the current Item from the itemList 
     * @return the current item from the itemList or NULL if all the items are processed.
     */
    public String getItem() {
        if (itemIndex >= itemList.size()) {
            return null;    // end of list
        }
        return itemList.get(itemIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Get the next Item from the itemList 
     * @return the next item from the itemList or NULL if all the items are processed.
     */
    public String getNextItem() {
        itemIndex ++;
        return getItem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of an `ArrayList` can easily be accessed by index.

From a web page (built by JSP), you can request a specific question using a query parameter, e.g. `showquestion.jsp?question=4`.

The JSP-generated page can then include a button to show next question by generating a new link (`<a href="showquestion.jsp?question=5">Next</a>`) with the next higher index, as long as there are more questions.